# How can I make a plugin ignore all non available tags?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I extracted all *static resources* (CSS, JS, IMG), the *views* (GSP) and *i18n* (messages*.properties) from my main Grails application into a separate plugin ('myguiplugin') in order to provide access for the frontend designer while keeping the core logic confidential.

Now working with that as it is would be pretty tough as the plugin (obviously) fails to work correctly when run *on it's own*.

The main reason being all the calls to tag's that are unavailable. Examples:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException: Error executing tag <g:render>
```

**Is there a way to have grails just ignore any error like that in order to be able to display the static parts of the application in the browser?**

Answer (score 0):

You could try a brute override of `GroovyPage.invokeTag()` method via `metaClass` (that's the one throwing this exception in Grails 1.3), but I'm unsure what will happen :D

Like:

```
def oldInvokeTag = GroovyPage.metaClass.invokeTag
GroovyPage.metaClass.invokeTag = { 
  String tagName, String tagNamespace, int lineNumber, Map attrs, Closure body ->

  try {
    // or do something more smart
    oldGormDelete.invoke(delegate, tagName, tagNamespace, lineNumber, attrs, body)
  }
  catch (e) {
    out.append("some unknown tag: $tagNamespace:$tagName")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Victor - where would I place that snippet in order to make it work? In BootStrap.groovy it fails with `ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error executing bootstraps: null
Message: null` - - - Do you happen to know of a variant that keeps template inclusions intact?

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Can only guess that - anywhere before page rendering. For instance, in controller action itself - just to test if the approach works at all.
Not sure what you mean about template inclusions, but with this approach you have full control over tags - you can handle any tag yourself.
OTOH, how come that you don't have `g:render` tag at all? Maybe you shouldn't run the plugin on its own, and run it inside *another* stripped-down application?